# How to display an image overlay with a code that uses pan and zoom?

Tags: android, android-imageview

I was using this code to display an image with pan and zoom:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_bms);

    com.example.karen.sample.util.TouchImageView img = new com.example.karen.sample.util.TouchImageView(this);
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.map_bms);
    img.setMaxZoom(4f);
    setContentView(img);
}
```

`TouchImageView.java` is [here](http://pastebin.com/Tf3XWgd8).

I'm real clueless as to how to overlay an image while using the code above. I'm very new to Android development.